# CoffeeScript scoping: sharing variables among functions in a single file

Tags: coffeescript, scope

Is it generally better practice to do this:

```
$ ->
  $('.thing-one').on 'click', ->
    window.myVar = 1

  $('.thing-two').on 'click', ->
    console.log window.myVar
```

or...

```
$ ->
  myVar = 0

  $('.thing-one').on 'click', ->
    myVar = 1

  $('.thing-two').on 'click', ->
    console.log myVar
```

Comment: The difference is of course using a global variable (ick) or sharing (closing over) the same variable in the parent scope. Does the situation *benefit* from a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ->
  @myVar = 0

  $('.thing-one').on 'click', =>
    @myVar = 1

  $('.thing-two').on 'click', =>
    console.log @myVar
```

Because the dynamic scope is at the window level, you don't need to declare it. `this` is the `window` object. But, you have to bind the context when doing callbacks, as shown with `=>`. doing it this way will preserve your dynamic scope. if you choose to put it on the window directly to avoid context, just use a good namespace. Coffeescript makes it easy:

```
window.someNameSpace ?= {}
someNameSpace.myVar = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between this code and my second code block in the question?

Comment: `myvar` is attached to 'this' or `@` such that the availability of the variable will changed based on what `this` is at any given time. for example, inside the click callback `this` is the click event, no longer the window. binding the callback to the scope from which it is called (`=>`)provides you access to the var. if you make that a normal skinny arrow, the context is lost. In your example, the `myvar` variable will only be available in the lexical scope.

Comment: as other folks have said though, sharing data between functions via shared vars should largely be avoided. counters are tricky though, since they require state somewhere, even if its in a closure. I might do it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldxkjxz3/1/